# Convert mp4 to RM with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using below command line to convert Mp4 to RM(RealMedia)

```
   ffmpeg -i "c:\video.mp4" -c:v h264 -s 1280x720 -b:v 800k  -r 30 "C:\output.rm"
```

Video Conversion is failing at %90 ..When i try with "mpeg2video" codec, everything goes fine.. but black screen while trying to play video

Comment: This is not a question about programming.

Comment: i didnt add any programming tag.

Comment: Please read before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers" ffmpeg doesnt count in for this?

Comment: Show complete log from command.